# Testing For a null returned value

Tags: java, android

In my app, I am parsing XML files -

```
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
```

using the following function

```
public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
         return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;
}
```

If everything works well than the program checks for the number of results.  My problem comes in when I run into a badly formed xml file. Such as when a WordPress file has the  tag inside.  What happens is my app crashes and when I look at the log the program has caught the exception

```
   } catch (SAXException e) {
System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
         return null;
```

which is fine.  Now what I want to do is test for null and then call the finish() to go back to the menu, rather than face a forced close.

I've used

```
if (null==doc){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry The XML File " + target +" is Misformed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       finish();
   }
```

and

```
if (doc==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry The XML File " + target +" is Misformed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           finish();
        }
```

to no avail. What would be the best way to handle these types of situations?

Still searching
I tried this

```
if(XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml)==null){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Badly Formed File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    finish();
```

}

Same issues - the line of code after the call is

```
int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);
```

The function code itself is

```
public static int numResults(Document doc){
        int res = -1;
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
        try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
        }catch(Exception e){
            res = -1;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The initial exception message being returned is message that is being returned for the function getXML is

> 03-27 12:46:26.917: I/System.out(10311): Wrong XML file structure: name expected >(position:START_TAG @29:27 in java.io.StringReader@405a3d30)

At that point it starts throwing fatal exceptions

Comment: What happens? Does the `Toast` appear?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer your question if you provided a little more of the code around/after this line `Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);`. My thinking is that sometime after your `if (doc == null)` check there's something which tries to call a method on `doc`.

Comment: No, the app force closes

Comment: Peter, the next line of code is
             int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code posted above wrapped in a function you can just make the whole thing called in an if loop i.e.

if (parseDoc(xml) == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry The XML File " + target +" is Misformed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

If your app is properly catching the exception it shouldn't be force closing unless something in your app is trying to access doc and is getting a null pointer.  The log of the exception would be useful in this case.

Comment: The next line of Code is trying to access doc 
The line is
    int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);
I'll your suggestion about wrapping the call in an if loop

thanks

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it so I can get the rep. =)  Given that the next line tries to execute something on the doc returned, I would bet the exception you are actually getting is a null pointer in that call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to throw the exceptions upwards and let the caller handle them. Catching the exception and returning null is bit unclean.